# Relation between Hausdorff measure and Lebesgue Measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

I have the following definition of $\alpha$-dimensional Hasudorff measure

> Let $E$ be subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$. Fix $\alpha \in [0, \infty)$, $\kappa \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $\epsilon > 0$. Then $\alpha$-dimensional Hausdorff measure (outer) is defined as:
> \begin{align}
>         H_{\alpha}(E) : = \displaystyle \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \; H^{{\epsilon}}_{\alpha}(E) = \sup_{\epsilon > 0} H^{{\epsilon}}_{\alpha}(E)
>     \end{align}

> Where for every $\epsilon>0$, define
> \begin{align*}
> H^{{\epsilon}}_{\alpha}(E) := \inf \left\{\sum_{j\geq1} \kappa r^{\alpha}_{j} : E \subset \bigcup_{j \geq 1} B(x_j, r_j) \text{ with } r_j < \epsilon \; \forall j \right\}
> \end{align*}
> where infimum is taken over all such $\epsilon$-covers of $E$.

$B(x_j, r_j)$ is ball in $\mathbb{R^n}$ under usual Euclidean metric.

I want to know what is the relation between Hausdorff measure of $E$ and Lebesgue measure of $E$. Also when does Hausdorff measure coincides with Lebesgue measure?

Comment: You can find an answer, for example, in Evans, Gariepy "Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions". n-Dimensional Hausdorff measure equal to Lebesgue in the n-dimensional space measure up to a constant.

Comment: @Danil Is there any way to know about that constant?

Comment: yes. If you choose the kappa equal to volume (Lebesgue measure) of unit ball in n-dimensional space divided by 2^n, then Hausdorff measure and Lebesgue measure coincide.